# Eclipse Neon subpackage

Tags: eclipse, package

I'm trying to create a subpackage (package inside another one) and I just can't. 
My Package Explorer it's on hierarchical already and when I try to create the subpackage like "package.child" for example, it just rename the principal package.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. If you don't have any classes in the parent package (`resources` in your case) it will not be shown as a separate node in the hierarchy (to save space).

If you add classes to the package it will be shown separately.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I just find it quite weird since I was using Luna back then, and I could create subpackages without having classes or resources in there.
So basically now the subpckage will only be created when already is something in the parent package?

Comment: No, it has been created but it just not being shown separately to save space.